# Why my If loop not moving for my second key code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need you guys to help as, I am new to programming. Why my second key code is not working. I'm not sure am I suppose to type that for my if loop. What I want my program to be is, when pressing "1", it goes to my first position that I set. And if I press "2" it will go to the second position if the current position is at my first position, if not it will go back to my start position.

Please help, below is my coding.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
            <title>Document</title>
            <style>

              body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background-image: url("TPHRG floorplan1.png");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                /* background-position: center; */
                background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
              }

              .robot_start_top {
                top: 280px;
                transition: top 2s;
              }

              .robot_start_left {
                position: fixed;
                left: 600px;
                transition: all 2s;
              }

              .robot_end_left {
                left: 570px;
              }

              .robot_end_top {
                top: 180px;
              }

              .robot1_start_left {
                position: fixed;
                left: 570px;
                transition: left 4s;
              }

              .robot1_end_left {
                left: 520px;
              }

              .robot2_start_left {
                position: fixed;
                left: 520px;
                transition: left 4s;
              }

              .robot2_end_left {
                left: 470px;
              }

              .robot3_end_down {
                top: 280px;
              }

              .robot3_end_right {
                left: 600px;
              }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body onkeydown="move(event)">
            <div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app">
              <img id="robot" style= width:30px; height:40px" src="pic_8.PNG">
            </div>

            <script>
              var move = function(event) {
                  if (event.keyCode === 49) {
                  const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
                  }, 0);
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
                  }, 2000);

                }

                  if (event.keyCode === 50) {
                    if (document.getElementById("app") === appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left"))
                    {
                      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
                    }, 0);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      appDiv.classList.add("robot2_end_left");
                    }, 2000);
                }

                else{
                  const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_down");
                  }, 2000);
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_right");
                  }, 0)
                  setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, 4000);

                }}
                    };
                </script>
            </body>
          </html>
```

Comment: According to how you wrote, pressing 2 (on your numeric keyboard, which laptops doesn't have normally!) when you're at your start position wont make anything happen?

Comment: But , when I cancel my if loop for the (document.getElementById("app") === appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left") , my program able to run. So I suspect, there program with my code for the second if loop.

Comment: @RickardElimää The number pad produces different keycodes. There's an error message in the console. BILAL seems to have fixed some issues, but they haven't bothered to explain what was fixed and how.

Comment: @BILAL addresses the issue with the second _if statement_. You forgot to declare your appDiv.

Comment: @Teemu, I try using BILAL code by adding in the console, but it still not working.

Comment: @Teemu I stand corrected. :) I just remember Chiong's thread from the last time, where it was purely numeric keyboard. S/he didn't listen to what I said back then about using variables to write readable code: "const KEY_NUMBER_ONE = 49; event.keyCode === KEY_NUMBER_ONE;", so I just assumed nothing had changed.

Comment: @Teemu, the reason for not doing that is, I'm linking this program to a robot. So currently, I'm not sure why I used BILAL code, but it only executes my else command beside my if command. Please guide me. So sorry about it.

Comment: At first, as both the answers are showing, move the `appDiv` declaration to the top of the function body. Then remove the other `appDiv` declarations, they will redeclare the constant, which gives you an error. A big problem is the first `if` condition when the keycode is `50`, the condition doesn't make any sense. You most likely need to check, if a specific class is in the classlist. And finally, you've also to remove some classes from the classlist while the image moves to new positions, otherwise when pressing the keys, the list just gets populated with all the classnames you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a quotation (") in the style attribute of the `img` tag. I'm fixing that in the code below.

**Important**

I strongly suggest that you refactor the code so it's easier to build on, and to debug. I show how that can be done in the code below. The "move" methods are pretty similar, so you can write one function to handle all of them, instead of having separate methods that does almost the same thing.

*Implementation*
You need to remove all classes before adding new ones, or you will end up with having lots of classes on the `#app` element. But if you remove the classes, `position: fixed` will disappear, so I broke that property out and placed it under `#app` in the CSS. I also moved your "style" properties into an CSS class – `#robot`.

I renamed "move" to "moveRobot" as well. Gives more context when the methods are called `moveTopLeft` within the moveRobot method.

I also removed the last zero in the CSS classes, so the robot is visible when you're running the snippet.

---

Down below, I implemented your thoughts, but commented out all `setTimeouts`, so it's easier to follow what's going on. What you will discover is that if you remove the classes, the transition wont happen, because `#app` doesn't remember the last position of `left` and `top`.

What you actually need is to set `left` and `top` in code (ex. `appDiv.styles.left = '300px'`), and abandon the idea of adding classes to the robot. I believe that this will make the code shorter as well.

```js
const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");  // Make this public so it's accessible everywhere;
var lastKeyStroke = -1;

var moveRobot = function(event) {
  const KEY_NUM_ONE = 49,
        KEY_NUM_TWO = 50;
         
  let keyStroke = event.keyCode;
  let pressedSameKeyTwice = keyStroke === lastKeyStroke; // not implemented

  removeAllPreviousClasses();    

  console.clear();

  if (keyStroke === KEY_NUM_ONE) {
    console.log("pressed 1");
    moveTopLeft();
  }
  else if (keyStroke === KEY_NUM_TWO) {
    console.log("pressed 2");
    moveTopRight();
  }
  else {
    console.log("pressed anything else");
    moveBottomRight();
  }
  
  lastKeyStroke = keyStroke;
}
      
function removeAllPreviousClasses() {
  appDiv.className = "";
}

function moveTopLeft() {
  //setTimeout(function() {
    appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
  //}, 0);
  //setTimeout(function() {
    appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
  //}, 2000);
}

function moveTopRight() {
  //setTimeout(function() {
    appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
  //}, 0);
  //setTimeout(function() {
    appDiv.classList.add("robot2_end_left");
  //}, 2000);
}

function moveBottomRight() {
    //setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_down");
    //}, 2000);
    //setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_right");
    //}, 0)
//setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, 4000);

    // removed excessive ending curly bracket
    // }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("TPHRG floorplan1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
}

#app {
  position: fixed;
  transition: left 2s, top 2s;
}

#robot { /* added these */
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
}

.robot3_end_down,   /* added these together */
.robot_start_top {
  top: 28px;
}

.robot_start_left {
  left: 60px;
}

.robot_end_left {
  left: 57px;
}

.robot_end_top {
  top: 18px;
}

.robot1_start_left {
  left: 57px;
}

.robot2_start_left,   /* added these together */
.robot1_end_left {
  left: 52px;
}

.robot2_end_left {
  left: 47px;
}

.robot3_end_right {
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body onkeydown="moveRobot(event)">
  <div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app">
    <img id="robot" src="https://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/android.png">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some problems with the if else conditions and the const `appDiv` in the code its working fine now

```js
var move = function (event) {
      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
      if (event.keyCode === 49) {

        setTimeout(function () {
          appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
        }, 0);
        setTimeout(function () {
          appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
        }, 2000);

      }

      else if (event.keyCode === 50) {
        console.log('2')

        if (document.getElementById("app") === appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left")) {
          const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
          setTimeout(function () {
            appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
          }, 0);
          setTimeout(function () {
            appDiv.classList.add("robot2_end_left");
          }, 2000);
        }
      }

      else {
        console.log('3')
        const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
        setTimeout(function () {
          appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_down");
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function () {
          appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_right");
        }, 0)
        setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(true); }, 4000);

      }
    }
      ;
```

```css
body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: url("TPHRG floorplan1.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      /* background-position: center; */
      background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
    }

    .robot_start_top {
      top: 280px;
      transition: top 2s;
    }

    .robot_start_left {
      position: fixed;
      left: 600px;
      transition: all 2s;
    }

    .robot_end_left {
      left: 570px;
    }

    .robot_end_top {
      top: 180px;
    }

    .robot1_start_left {
      position: fixed;
      left: 570px;
      transition: left 4s;
    }

    .robot1_end_left {
      left: 520px;
    }

    .robot2_start_left {
      position: fixed;
      left: 520px;
      transition: left 4s;
    }

    .robot2_end_left {
      left: 470px;
    }

    .robot3_end_down {
      top: 280px;
    }

    .robot3_end_right {
      left: 600px;
    }
```

```html
<body onkeydown="move(event)">
  <div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app">
    <img id="robot" style=width:30px; height:40px"
      src="https://petapixel.com/assets/uploads/2019/02/mooncompositemain-800x800.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, It still not able to works. Could you please help. thanks

Comment: This bunch of code is pretty much useless, if you won't explain what you've changed and why.

Comment: `if(document.getElementById("app") === appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left"))`. How do you think this condition ever will pass?